# removing duplicates from a list of django models

Tags: python, django

I have a list of Django Models objects which i got from a query set, but there are duplicate objects in that list can one one tell me how to remove those

I tried this but it gives me empty list didn't worked

```
print(somemodels) #union of some quersets as list
>>> [<SomeModel: 1>, <SomeModel: 1>, <SomeModel: 2>]
cleaned_up_list = []

for somemodel in somemodels:
    print (type(some model))
    >>>> <class 'SomeModel.models.SomeModel'>
    if somemodel not in somemodels:
        print ("SomeModel is not already in :" cleaned_up_list)
        cleaned_up_list.append(somemodel)

print ("Very Final Results :", cleaned_up_list)
```

the cleaned up list is still empty? so it didn't worked that way, as you can there are same two models in `some models` with same `pk` of `1` i want to remove those duplicates can one please help me to remove duplicate django models from a list of django models?

Comment: Use .distinct() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct ?

Comment: it works with `lists` too?

Comment: how could something from a list not be  in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code :

```
if somemodel not in somemodels:
    print ("SomeModel is not already in :" cleaned_up_list)
    cleaned_up_list.append(somemodel)
```

By :

```
if somemodel not in cleaned_up_list:
    print ("SomeModel is not already in :" cleaned_up_list)
    cleaned_up_list.append(somemodel)
```

Because in your first code the test will always be true since you are testing if the element is existing in a list you are iterating on.

Answer (score 2):

I saw your comment of union some querysets as list, so I'm assuming they are of the same model objects. You could union the querysets by doing:

```
queryset = queryset1 | queryset2 | queryset3
```

The result is not a list but still a queryset. Then you can simply do:

```
queryset = queryset.distinct()
```